2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire
In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected from an earlier thread have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers. 
Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as our back up questions for a total of 5 questions.
As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes.Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.
Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.
Good luck to all of the candidates!
Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.
To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):



How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments? 
How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
In your opinion, what do moderators do? 
A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that? 
In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?



Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen


How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?


The user should receive some friendly hints that they are being problematic. If that doesn't help I would discuss with other moderators and then there is the possibility of a temporary suspension.


How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?


If it seemed very unreasonable to me I would probably discuss it with the other moderator; if only borderline I'd just let it go.


In your opinion, what do moderators do?


Deal with flags (by the way I have a 100% helpful flag record on MathOverflow and am a moderator at CSTheory) and some other things discussed in A Theory of Moderation.


A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?


That seems okay, what I write here tends to be very neutral and polite, as I am aware that each comment is a nano-publication of sorts.


In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?


I don't feel that it would "make me more effective" but it could be an interesting way to contribute to the site and stay involved.

Attack68


How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?


Context is important. Simply because a large number of comments/flags have been raised may mean the answer is controversial but not offensive or inaccurate. There is an important distinction. If the user has generated valuable answers by assumption he has inherent knowledge of the matter. Action (polite discussion, warning, suspension) should be taken only in an case of obvious violation and or any form of unnecessary additional content.


How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?


Ignore it. Unless I felt very strongly in which case I might attempt to reverse it. By the same token, if I had closed a question and another mod re-opened it I would also probably let that go. There is potentially too much work to argue about a single question, which is obviously subjective.


In your opinion, what do moderators do?


Maintain the forum at least to a state where its intended purpose is served to the community. Eliminate offensive content and steer those who post content in the wrong place unwittingly.


A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?


Completely indifferent. I would not have observed it if I had never read this question, and, personally, I have never attached any form of importance to any other moderators posts.


In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?


Reputation points are of no relevance or value to me, nor is being a moderator. None will make me 'more effective'. I am interested in the Quant Finance forum because I think it serves a useful purpose on the internet. It is important to me because it piques my interest and provokes ideas in an industry I have worked for 15 years. I would like to assist in safeguarding the space and promoting it in the future to better serve those goals, which are both selfish and idealistic, however, conveniently for the wider community, they also align with the notion of altruism.
